# Restore a chained virtualbox .vdi from backup?

Tags: virtualbox, restore, vdi

I have a windows guest vm in virtualbox on a linux host. The base vdi and all snapshots are located on a SSD for performance reasons. A snapshot is taken every night and a rsync backup is made to an external USB disk. When the system crashes once in a while, I have corrupted disks as chkdsk shows me. Then I don't know if the SSD or the backup (or both) are corrupted. For that reason I have a script that evaluates a sha256sum of every .vdi after the backup and stores the values in a file. If a file gets corrupted, the time, date and size are still the same but the checksum differs. This way I can identify if and which of the files is corrupted. If the file on the SSD is corrupted and the backup is not, then I want to restore the backup .vdi to the SSD. Now my question is if I can do that. Will the snapshot chain be fully functional after I restored a .vdi that has childs, i.e. is not the 'current state'? Or is virtualbox altering previous (chained) snapshots at any time? I assume that only the 'current state' is altered, no matter, what I do in the guest (chkdsk /r, sfc /scannow, System Updates etc.). Is that correct?